# mfc c++ update text file from edit control

Tags: c++, mfc, save, cfile

I know how to read a txt file, and show it's contents in an edit control, but how do I write to a txt file updating/overwriting it's contents from an edit control?

i've looked everywhere, and although I can write to a file with set text, I want to be able to write into the edit control box, and then click the update button which will update the notes txt file.

Comment: What have you tried? Considering you know how to read file/set window text, you should be able to do the inverse easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it in two steps. First read the edit control into a CString variable. Then write the CString variable to file.